# The structure of locally compact abelian groups by D. L. Armacost.

Tags: reference-request, topological-groups

I do not have access to this important book: The structure of locally compact abelian groups by D. L. Armacost. I need to the Example 6.4 of this book. I will be grateful if you can help

Comment: Can you get it through interlibrary loan?